# Why the book used $c_x$ notation to denote a number in Taylor's remainder theorem?

Tags: notation

> (Taylor's remainder) Assume that $f(x)$ has $n+1$ continuous derivatives on an interval
> $\alpha\le x \le\beta$, and let the point $a$ belong to the interval.
> For nth degree Taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ let $R_n(x)\equiv
>  f(x)-P_n(x)$ denote the remainder in approximating $f(x)$ by $P_n(x)$.
> Then
>
> $$R_n(x)=\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(c_x), \quad  \alpha\le
>  x\le \beta$$with $c_x$ an unknown point between $a$ and $x$.

They denoted a number between $a$ and $x$ by $c_x$. so why not just write $c$ instead? and what does subscript $x$ exactly mean here and in general in mathematics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just to remind you that the number depends on $x$.

Comment: I see. thank you for the answer.